# How to check whether the QTreeViews item is expanded or collapsed in delegate?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

Is there any way to find if an item in a tree view is in which state in PyQt5? ie, expanded or collapsed. I need to get the value in the custom delegate class that I have created.

```
class SummaryDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
       def __init__(self, treeView):
           super(SummaryDelegate, self).__init__()
           self.treeView = treeView
           self.headerItems = self.collectDictKeys(summarySectionData)
    
       def collectDictKeys(self, data):
           collection = []
           for key, value in data.items():
               collection.append(key)
               if isinstance(value, dict):
                   collection.extend(self.collectDictKeys(value))
    
           return collection
    
       def paint(self, painter, option, index):
           dataItem = index.data()
           
           if dataItem in self.headerItems:
                   pass
           else:
               if type(index.data()) == str:
                    pass
               else:
                    pass
    
               newRec = QRect(option.rect)
               newRec.setLeft(0)
               painter.fillRect(newRec, QColor(240, 245, 255))
```

Comment: What about using [`self.treeView.isExpanded(index)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreeview.html#isExpanded)? Also, please fix your example by following the guidelines about [formatting code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362).

Comment: Is there any function to check whether an item is selected or not too? @musicamante

Comment: Thank you @musicamante, It worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `paint`, `option.state` will give you the [state](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyle.html#StateFlag-enum) of the item including whether it's open (i.e. expanded) or not. It also has information about other state parameters of the item such as whether it's selected or not. For find out if the item is open or not you can use something like `int(option.state) & QtWidgets.QStyle.State_Open`. Similarly, `int(option.state) & QtWidgets.QStyle.State_Selected` will tell you whether the item is selected or not.

Comment: I am able to access the child node. But it's not showing the parent item is selected or not. 

       if int(option.state) & QtWidgets.QStyle.State_Selected:
           print(index.data())

index.data() is only showing child data.

Comment: Hey, If anyone wants to check if your item is open, use `int(option.state) & QtWidgets.QStyle.State_Open`